# jQuery.append() doesn't work when using a variable as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that is supposed to append some HTML:

```
function showProd(id,afid)
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "getprod.php",
        data : {pid : id},
        async : false,
        success : function(data)
        {
            var tab = data.split("::");
            var selec = "#"+afid;
            alert(selec);
            $(selec).attr("data-pid",tab[0]).attr("data-intv",tab[1]).attr("data-death",tab[3]);
            $(selec).append("<div class='prod_img'></div>");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that the `.append()` doesn’t do anything, but on the other hand, the `.attr()` works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: youre appending an empty div, are you sure its not being appended but you just havent noticed

Comment: and when I replace the variable selector whith a string selector it works

Comment: hmm your sure ? you lock inside your selecteor ? try this console.log($(select).find('.prod_img')) after you append and come back and told me if you find it.

Comment: well I am using the navigator inspector to find if the div exists or not
and that's how I find that the attr() is working
and also replacing $(selec).append() with $("#theid").append() works

Comment: check if $(selec).length is greater than zero

Comment: your sure all time have 3 id's on your array tab ? maiby you have some error in console, press F12 and check. I was try on stackoverflow page to do simple code like this `var a=''comment-copy";$('.'+a).append("<div class='prod_img'></div>");` and work, check your jquery version please.

Comment: using "alert($(selec).length);" gives 1

Comment: @Laurentiu the console.log gives
Object { 0: <div.prod_img>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → lezero, selector: "#b1p1 .prod_img" }
is that mean that the div exists but not shown in the navigator inspector??

Comment: yes, this maiby because your ajax is syncrouns and maiby you have anthor function syncrons who manipulate DOM. Be sure your first render your DOM and after that you manipulate him, do this asyncrons or after ajax success.

Comment: @Laurentiu : Allright thanks a lot
It's a rendering problem as you said